# How can I pass a class into a method so the method can get a reference to that class and act upon it?

Tags: c#, generics

I have this code in my app:

```
var appManagementPage = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppManagementPage>();
if (Device.RuntimePlatform is Device.iOS)
    await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(appManagementPage);
else
      await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(appManagementPage);
```

and

```
var testPage = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestPage>();
if (Device.RuntimePlatform is Device.iOS)
    await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(testPage);
else
    await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(testPage);
```

I would like to move the functionality into a method something like this:

```
private static async Task NewMethod()
{
    var page = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppManagementPage>();
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform is Device.iOS)
        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
    else
        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
}
```

But how can I pass the class objects `AppManagementPage` or `TestPage` into the method and make it so that it will work to open any pages?

Comment: Convert it to a generic method: `private static async Task NewMethod<T>()`.

Comment: If that works it would be great.  Can you suggest to me the code to call it and what the method would like in an answer and I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may convert it into a [generic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods):

```
private static async Task NewMethod<T>()
{
    var page = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform is Device.iOS)
        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
    else
        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
}
```

Then, you can call it like this:

```
NewMethod<AppManagementPage>();
NewMethod<TestPage>();
```

Additionally, if `AppManagementPage` and `TestPage` are derived from the same base class or implement the same interface, you could (actually should) add a [constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to the method signature to restrict the type arguments it can accept. For example:

```
private static async Task NewMethod<T>() where T : IPage
```